# SwiftUI: How to Navigate from one view to another by clicking on a button

Tags: button, swiftui, navigationlink

I am trying to move from one view to another, I have used NavigationLink as following:

```
        @State private var isActive = false


        NavigationLink(destination: DetailsView(),
                       isActive: $isActive) {
                        Text("")}
        Button(action: {
            print ("Clicked")
            self.isActive = true
        }){
            Text("More Details")
                .font(.headline)
                .bold()
                .padding(.all, 10)
                .padding(.leading, 10)
                .padding(.trailing, 10)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .background(Color.orange.frame(width: 300, height: 50) .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)))

        }
```

Unfortunately did not work!! The button did not take me to Details View!! I have already checked most of the solutions over here but nothing worked for me :( Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a `NavigationLink` you have to wrap it in a `NavigationView`

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {   // <--- add this
            NavigationLink(destination: DetailsView()) {
                Text("ADD TO CART")
                    .font(.headline)
                    .bold()
                    .padding(.all, 10)
                    .padding(.leading, 10)
                    .padding(.trailing, 10)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .background(Color.orange.frame(width: 300, height: 50) .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)))

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Worked!!